# Templates can be used only with field access expressions , access properties, array index of a dimension or a parameter custom indexer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this model:

```
public class Proyecto
{
    #region Atributos
    [DisplayName("Código")]
    public string ProyectoID { get; set; }

    public string OportunidadID {get;set;}
    [DisplayName("Nombre")]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Fecha inicio")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    public DateTime FechaInicio { get; set; }

    public string CodigoCliente { get; set; }

    public string TipoClienteTelco { get; set; }

    public string Sector { get; set; }

    public string AmbitoProyecto { get; set; }

    public string DescripcionServicio { get; set; }

    public string TipoServicio { get; set; }

    public DateTime CierreOperativo { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    public DateTime FechaCierreTeorica { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayName("Fecha fin")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    public DateTime FechaCierreReal { get; set; }

    public string EnquestaCalidad { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Estado")]
    public Valoracion Estado { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Tendencia")]
    public Valoracion Tendencia { get; set; }

    public virtual Oportunidad Oportunidad { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AsientoProyecto> Asientos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<IngresoProyecto> Ingresos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AsignacionProyecto> Asignaciones { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comentario> Comentarios { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

And in my view, I try to insert a @Html.EditorFor using this sintax:

```
<tr>
    <th>Ingresos</th>
     @foreach (var item in Model.Ingresos)
     {
         if (item.Fecha.Month < DateTime.Now.Month && item.Fecha.Year <= DateTime.Now.Year)
         {
             <td>item.Cantidad €</td>
         }
         else
         {
          @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Ingresos.Where(i => i.ID == item.ID));
         }
     }
 </tr>
```

What i'm trying to do is to add a input textbox for updating the "Ingreso" of the Icollection of the "Proyecto" (my Model is a Proyecto)

But I get the following error:
"Templates can be used only with field access expressions , access properties, array index of a dimension or a parameter custom indexer"

Can anyone explain me what I'm doing wrong here?
Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Ingresos.Where(i => i.ID == item.ID));
```

with

```
@Html.EditorFor(item => item);
```

And it would be a good idea to also replace

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Ingresos)
```

with

```
@foreach (IngresoProyecto item in Model.Ingresos)
```

It this way your model type should be properly identified and the issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In the EditorFor template you are trying to evaluate an expression to yield a result which is against the use of templates where as create a variable to get the result what you expect then pass to editor template.

```
{
    var filteredIngreso = Model.Ingresos.Where(i => i.ID == item.ID);
    @Html.EditorFor(model => filteredIngreso);
}
```